# How can I identify questions having same context ? (Contextual Analysis)

Tags: javascript, node.js, machine-learning, nlp, unsupervised-learning

I want to apply contextual analysis on a set of questions I have , and I want to group the questions those are having same context.

I am doing this task in NodeJS, so have worked with multiple npm packages for the same. But I am not getting any satisfactory result. Can I apply any ML library for the task mentioned ?

**Questions I have:**

Tell me the price of your product ?

What is the costing ?

Share me the pricing details

Show me a demo

Can we have a demonstration

**Result I want:**

[
Tell me the price of your product ?

What is the costing ?

Share me the pricing details
],

[
Show me a demo

Can we have a demonstration
]

---

Let me know if any additional information required

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the question is too wide. What do you handle ? a json structure like [{context:'ctx 1',question : 'tell me the price... ?'},{..},{..}, etc...]  ?

Comment: Yes, Exactly, Initially, I have an array with list of questions and ultimately I will group them in JSON (questions with similar context together)